# How to set DropDownList's selected value inside a Repeater?

Tags: c#, asp.net, data-binding, drop-down-menu, repeater

I need to create a group of `DropDownList`s to show and allow change of a property group for an item.

I have the following code on my ASP page.

```
<asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="repeaterProperties">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <p><asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="ddProperty" OnInit="ddProperty_OnInit" /><p>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

The `ddProperty_OnInit` populates the `DropDownList` with all the possible values with a database query.

How can I set the selected value of each created `DropDownList` according to the `Repeater`'s source data?

Let's say, for example, that we have the possible property values of `A`, `B` and `C`.
If the database output for the `Repeater` contains two of those values, `A` and `B`, the `Repeater` outputs two `DropDownList`s, both with all 3 values availabla and the first one with `A` as selected value and the second one with `B` as selected value.

**Edit:**
It seems that adding `OnItemDataBound="repeater_ItemDataBound"` to the `Repeater` and selecting the appropriate value in there is not the way to go in my case. This is because I also need to save the possibly changed values to a database.

The `ItemDataBound` event of the `Repeater` is fired before the `OnClick` event on a `Button` and changes the selected values to their old values before the new selections can be saved.

Any suggestion on how to work around this?

*Current code:*

```
<asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="repeaterJako" OnItemDataBound="repeater_ItemDataBound">
<ItemTemplate>
    <asp:DropDownList id="ddJako" runat="server" OnInit="ddJako_OnInit">
    </asp:DropDownList><br />
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
<asp:Button runat="server" id="updateButton" Text="Save" OnClick="update_OnClick" />
```

In the code-behind, `ddJako_OnInit` populates the drop down list with all the possible choises, while the `repeater_ItemDataBound` uses the method suggested by Bryan Parker to select the proper value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe I'm misunderstanding something about your question... but it seems like this is exactly what OnItemDataBound is for.  :)

Use FindControl to get a reference to your DropDownList in the event handler.  Also check to make sure the item is not the header/footer.  The example from MSDN does both these things:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.repeater.onitemdatabound.aspx

Comment: Yes, that is what I was looking for.
After reading the link, all that was left for me to do was to figure out what to cast the DataItem into.

Comment: @jwalkerjr I did, untill I found out that it did not help my situation. Well, I did figure it out just a minute ago, so might as well. It's a good answer and mine will only add to it.

Answer (score 1):

In regard the problem I specified in my edit, the time of the `DataBind` plays an important role. I used to do the databinding in the `Page_Init` event, which caused the `repeater_ItemDataBound` event to be fired before the `button_OnClick` event.

The solution was to move the databinding to the `Page_PreRender` event.
The population of the `DropDownList` with all the choises is still done in its `OnInit` event.